# How to view git objects and index without using git

Tags: git, macos, version-control, terminal

Using the OS X terminal,

How an you view the contents of these files as plain text?

Comment: These files are inherently not plain-text, and to view them as such, you need a program which converts them from their format into text. Git is a program with components designed to do precisely that. I would be extremely surprised if anyone has written another one.

Comment: So the objects (specifically commit objects) won't convert to plain text?

Comment: They are *at least* compressed using zlib (deflate) compression.

Comment: @CoreyFloyd Of course they'll convert to plain text! That's what `git` is for!

Comment: This can be broken into three questions: 1) calculate the hash: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225313/how-does-git-compute-file-hashes 2) If on a loose object, DEFLATE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178566/deflate-command-line-tool 3) If in a packfile... learn how packfiles work and reimplement them :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478023/is-the-git-binary-diff-algorithm-delta-storage-standardized/27462206 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76002/git-pack-file-entry-format

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at [“Object storage format” in Git User Manual](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#object-details).

It is raw compressed data using [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/).  One can use `zpipe` from the 'zlib1g-dev' package. Compile [the example](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/zpipe.c) with `gcc -o zpipe zpipe.c -lz`.  It is not a standard `.gz` or something.

```
./zpipe -d < .git/objects/02/43019ddb4d94114e5a8580eec01baeea195133
```

prints the content of the blob (header+data)

If you want to check the SHA-1, you have to put the uncompressed blob in a file (`myblob`) and do

```
sha1sum myblob
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for packed objects (ones that have been in the repository for a while).

Comment: Do you mean that the object files contain only the DEFLATE payload, and not other metadata fields as specified in: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1952.txt, so this is why `gunzip` won't work?

Answer (score 17):

```
alias deflate="perl -MCompress::Zlib -e 'undef $/; print uncompress(<>)'"

deflate .git/objects/4b/3083256dedabd68e839d7717aa785424119990 | sha1sum
4b3083256dedabd68e839d7717aa785424119990  -
```

Comment: This answer works on any machine with perl, whereas the accepted answer refers to a specific tool `zpipe` which isn't immediately available on macOS, for example. It would be good if it described what the `perl` invocation was doing, though: loading the `zlib` module from the perl stdlib, then decompressing stdin. I love perl!

Comment: I upvoted but it should be named "inflate"  compress=deflate, uncompress=inflate

Answer (score 12):

I'm going to interpret your question in a different way.  If you want to understand what the objects files ARE, you can use git to view them directly, without navigating the history log or using git checkout, diff etc.  For instance:

For the file `.git/objects/04/a42e9a7282340ef0256eaa6d59254227b8b141`

Run the command

```
git show 04a42e
```

which combines the `04` from `/04/` and the first four characters of the remaining number `a42e`.

```
> git show 04a42e
commit 04f7db976fa54c72fcc6350dd7d0aa06cb249df6
Author: Alex Brown <alex@XXXX.XXX>
Date:   Fri Jan 8 11:02:21 2010 +0000
a text file

diff --git a/1.txt b/1.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..04a42e9
--- /dev/null
+++ b/1.txt
@@ -0,0 +1,3 @@
+Woo
+# boo
+# choo
```

This one is a commit, other objects may be file blobs, trees, etc.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to view plain text form of git objects (commits and/or blobs i.e. file contents) *without* using git, it would not be easy, especially if repository is packed.  Can't you install git locally, in your home directory (or its equivalent on MacOS X)?

The format for **loose** objects, stored as files in `.git/objects/` fan-out directory, e.g. `.git/objects/02/43019ddb4d94114e5a8580eec01baeea195133` (the fan-out directory and file name form SHA-1 identifier of object), is described e.g. in [Chapter 9.2 "Git Objects"](http://progit.org/book/ch9-2.html) of "Pro Git" book (available on-line for free) and [Chapter 7.1 "How Git Stores Objects"](http://book.git-scm.com/7_how_git_stores_objects.html) of "Git Community Book".

The **pack** format, where set of objects is stored in single file in `.git/objects/pack/`, e.g. `.git/objects/pack/pack-1db7aa96d95149a4dd341490a3594181a24415ee.pack`, is described in [Documentation/technical/pack-format.txt](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/technical/pack-format.txt) and in [Chapter 7.5 "The Packfile"](http://book.git-scm.com/7_the_packfile.html) of "Git Community Book" (and mentioned in [Chapter 9.4 "Packfiles"](http://progit.org/book/ch9-4.html) of "Pro Git")

---

If you want to find latest commit, take a look first at `.git/HEAD` file to find current branch.  It would contain something like the following:

```
ref: refs/heads/master
```

(if it contains SHA-1, you can take it as id of last commit, and skip a step).  Then check e.g. `.git/refs/heads/master` to find where the branch points to.  It would contain SHA-1 of a commit, e.g.:

```
dbc1b1f71052c084a84b5c395e1cb4b5ae526fcb
```

Last (most recent) commit would be probably in loose format; in this example it would be in `.git/objects/db/c1b1f71052c084a84b5c395e1cb4b5ae526fcb` file.

Answer (score 0):

The index is stored under `.git/index`.

It is a binary uncompressed format specified at: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/index-format.txt, so the only way to read it is with a tool like `hd`.

The `index` file contains a list of files with their metadata, including inode, permissions, and modification time. It also contains the SHA-1 of the content, which is stored as an object, which means that when you do `git add` it may create new objects.

I encourage you to create a simple test repo like `git init init && cd init && echo a > a && git add a`, and then `hd .git/index` to verify the format field by field.

The following question focuses more on the index: [What does the git index contain EXACTLY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084921/what-does-the-git-index-exactly-contain)