# Is there any way to get curl to decompress a response without sending the Accept headers in the request?

Tags: curl, gzip

Is there any way to get curl to decompress a response without sending the Accept-encoding headers in the request?

I'm trying to debug an issue where the order of the Accept-encoding headers may be relevant, but I also need to know what the response is.  If I just send `-H 'Accept-encoding: gzip` and the server gzips the response, curl won't decompress it.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Probably the easiest thing to do is just use `gunzip` to do it:

```
curl -sH 'Accept-encoding: gzip' http://example.com/ | gunzip -
```

Or there's also `--compressed`, which `curl` will decompress (I believe) since it knows the response is compressed. But, not sure if that meets your needs.

Comment: Works like a charm!  Any way to get it to work when there are output headers too, or is that asking too much?

Comment: @Jun-DaiBates-Kobashigawa You can use -D to dump headers to a file, e.g. `-D headers.txt` and it will save them to the file out of band so it won't screw up your gzip encoding.

Answer (score 69):

`curl --compressed http://example.com` requests gzipped-compressed data and uncompresses it before writing to disk.

Comment: With the `--compressed` flag, curl will send an `Accept-Encoding: gzip` request header.  It sounds like that might be fine for what the op wants, but it's not directly satisfying the question.  (I found this question because I actually do want curl to decompress without sending the header)