# Translating Python HTTP request to curl

Tags: python, json, http, curl, request

I have the code below in Python which is making a POST request for an OAuth2 token. It uses basic authentication. 
The code works fine, but I would like to "translate it" to curl.

The code:

```
#Authorization: Basic c29tZV91c2VyOnBhc3M=
#some_user:pass = base64decode('c29tZV91c2VyOnBhc3M=') 

def get_access_token():
burp0_url = "https://myurl:443/api/oauth/token"
burp0_headers = {"Accept": "application/json", "Authorization": "Basic c29tZV91c2VyOnBhc3M=", "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Connection": "close", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", "User-Agent": "okhttp/3.0.1"}
burp0_data={"grant_type": "client_credentials"}
return json.loads(requests.post(burp0_url, headers=burp0_headers,
data=burp0_data).text)['access_token']
```

My guess was be that it would look something like this:

```
curl -v -XPOST -H 'Authorization: Basic c29tZV91c2VyOnBhc3M=' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Connection: close' --header 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' --header 'User-Agent: okhttp/3.0.1' --data '{"grant_type": "client_credentials"}' https://myurl:443/api/oauth/token
```

However I keep getting a HTTP/1.1 400 and the following
* Failed writing body (0 != 10)  
* Failed writing data 
* stopped the pause stream! 
* Closing connection 0

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to copy the `"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` header into your curl command.

This would also suggest the data is not submitted as a JSON string as you're currently doing, but as regular form data. You can probably use `-F 'grant_type=client_credentials'` for that and drop the `--data` argument.

Comment: I'm not sure if -F option requires the Content-Type to be "multipart".  I changed the request to be like      `curl -v -XPOST -H 'Authorization: Basic c29tZV91c2VyOnBhc3M=' --header "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Connection: close' --header 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' --header 'User-Agent: okhttp/3.0.1' --form "grant_type=client_credentials" https://myurl:443/api/oauth/token` (**I am getting a 200 now but still getting the * Failed writing body (0 != 10) * Failed writing data * Closing connection 0 - Thanks, though**

Comment: Are you piping the results anywhere? A quick Google search seems to indicate that the error means that curl received 10 bytes but was only able to write 0 bytes to the requested output destination (`-o`). Since you're not providing a `-o` argument, I'm wondering if perhaps you're sending the output somewhere that's not expecting it or that you don't have permission to write to.

Comment: See also [this question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1017773/curl-for-file-download-via-post) which has a similar error output

Comment: I also tried with the -o. It creates a file with gibberish. Something like `?       ?î- -0??¦E÷_Ç¦mL¶gB¦>%¶¦Éõð"¦+íÎaf¥4½óÍðÂ?+=h¶w}-¦y=Þ¦$6` - Could it be due to the encoding used by the terminal (I'm using Windows)

Comment: That looks like gzip-compressed data, exactly what your `Accept-Encoding` header is requesting. You should be able to have curl decompress it automatically by [adding `--compressed` to the command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8365089/1941241)

Comment: Thank you @rickdenhaan, it was exactly that option that was missing! so my final request ended something like: `curl -v -XPOST -H 'Authorization: Basic c29tZV91c2VyOnBhc3M=' --header "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Connection: close' --header 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' --header 'User-Agent: okhttp/3.0.1' --form "grant_type=client_credentials" https://myurl:443/api/oauth/token --compressed -o outfile.txt` - Thanks again for you patience!