# PHP's 'gzuncompress' function in the shell?

Tags: php, bash, compression, zlib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deflate command line tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178566/deflate-command-line-tool)

Yes, I know I can use PHP itself on the shell, but I need this functionality in a script that is deployed before PHP is available.

I've tried `gzip` and `unzip` but either my parameters are incorrect or they plain just don't use the same compression.

I want to use this in a bash script. Going into a higher level scripting language isn't an option.

---

I wrote the following PHP script for testing purposes:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?
  $contents = file_get_contents( $argv[1] );
  $data = gzuncompress( $contents );
  echo substr( $data, 0, 20 ) . "\n";
?>
```

This outputs what I expect (the beginning of the decoded data).

If I pass the same file to `gunzip`:

```
$ gunzip -c data
gzip: data: not in gzip format
```

If I try `unzip`:

```
$ unzip data
Archive:  data
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of data2 or
        data2.zip, and cannot find data2.ZIP, period.
```

---

As suggested, and given that there is no other practical way, I went with the solution presented in the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178566/deflate-command-line-tool).
But given that I wanted to avoid moving to another scripting language (and introducing another dependency) I went with all of them:

```
_uncompressedData=
if hash perl 2>&-; then
  echo "Using Perl for decompression..." >&2
  _uncompressedData=$(perl -MCompress::Zlib -e 'undef $/; print uncompress(<>)' < compressed.bin || true)
elif hash ruby 2>&-; then
  echo "Using Ruby for decompression..." >&2
  _uncompressedData=$(ruby -rzlib -e 'print Zlib::Inflate.new.inflate(STDIN.read)' < compressed.bin || true)
elif hash php 2>&-; then
  echo "Using PHP for decompression..." >&2
  _uncompressedData=$(php -r "echo gzuncompress(file_get_contents('php://stdin'));" < compressed.bin || true)
elif hash python 2>&-; then
  echo "Using Python for decompression..." >&2
  _uncompressedData=$(python -c "import zlib,sys;print zlib.decompress(sys.stdin.read())" < compressed.bin || true)
else
  echo "Unable to find decompressor!" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

These 4 versions produced the exact same output with my test cases.

Comment: How do you use gzip? Try `gzip -c /etc/motd | gunzip -c | diff /etc/motd -`

Comment: Ironically, *both* gzip *and* zip use exactly the same algorithm. They just happen to have more than the raw data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The format that `gzuncompress` expects is the raw zlib format without the gzip header. This is the format you get by default if you use the zlib library's C API.

You can uncompress this format using the `zpipe` command-line utility. The source code for this utility is found in `examples/zpipe.c` in the [zlib](http://zlib.net/) source code distribution. But this program is not compiled and installed by default. There are no widely deployed command-line utilities that accept the raw zlib format.

If you want to use the gzip format instead (the one with the friendly header which `gzip` & `gunzip` deal with) from PHP then you need to use [gzencode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzencode.php) & [gzdecode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php) instead of [gzcompress](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php) & [gzuncompress](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzuncompress.php).

Comment: Sadly, I do not control the compressed data.

Comment: Then I'm afraid that, even though you said it wasn't an option, you have to consider bundling a utility like `zpipe` or using one of the scripting languages to do the decompression. The [Deflate command line tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178566/deflate-command-line-tool) question linked to by [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](http://stackoverflow.com/users/20862/ignacio-vazquez-abrams) suggests methods for Python, Ruby, and Perl. Plus you know how to do it in PHP.