# Decompress string compressed by php's gzcompress()

Tags: php, rust, gzip, zlib, deflate

So I have data compressed in php in this way:

`$compressed = gzcompress($pairs, 9);`

When I try to decompress obtained data with rust in this way:

```
let mut d = flate2::read::GzDecoder::new(compressed_pairs.as_bytes());
let mut s = String::new();
d.read_to_string(&mut s).unwrap();

println!("{}", s);
```

I get this error - `` thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Custom { kind: InvalidInput, error: "invalid gzip header" }', ``

As I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035057/phps-gzuncompress-function-in-node-js) gzcompress is similar to gzencode, but with different header.
Is it possible to decode it in Rust?

[I found out here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184546/phps-gzuncompress-function-in-the-shell) a C library and I thought that I can connect it to my Rust code, but may be there are simpler solution?

Comment: Is this helpful: https://docs.rs/compress/0.1.2/compress/zlib/index.html

Comment: Or more probably: https://docs.rs/compress/latest/compress/flate/index.html since it looks like `gzcompress` produces raw compressed data with no header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read your documentation.

The [PHP function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php) you reference "compresses the given string using the ZLIB data format" (despite being called `gzcompress`, but that's the PHP standard library for you, never trust any function names). But you're trying to decompress it gzip data, not zlib. The docs even say "This is *not* the same as gzip compression".

You probably therefore want to use [a zlib decoder](https://docs.rs/flate2/latest/flate2/read/struct.ZlibDecoder.html).