# Commit directly to a bare repository

Tags: git

### Some Context

#### what this fits into

A collaboration focused web application that offers git hosting (as `bare` repos)

#### what we want to do

Allow users to add a set of files directly to their existing repositories.

### My Question

#### Is there a tool or method to manually create a commit that only involves adding new files to a git repo?

We're able to do this now using temporary server-side sparse checkouts but we would like to optimize this process.

Comment: What do you mean "create a commit that only involves adding new files"? How is that any different than a normal commit?

Comment: It sounds like you want to have a web application where people can upload files, and those files, on the backend, get committed to a git repo?  What language is the web site in? You would likely need to find a library to interact with git for whatever language you are using.

Comment: @rally25rs We are using a python wsgi app but we're not as concerned with what language or packages we need to use to do this. Any method can be triggered from the site as a subprocess.

Comment: I'm also interested in this topic; I need it for phorkie, my git based pastebin tool.

Comment: This issue has been on my back burner while working out other parts of the platform but I will need to readdress it soon. If no module or library can be found I would like to start one as a lightweight open source project. For our platform making this a Python module makes sense but it would be beneficial to do it in a common format with multiple language bindings. If anyone is interested in contributing or leading this small project please let me know.

Comment: I just want to say you're not mad, and I hope one of us finds the answer and puts it here for the next wanderers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [plumbing and porcelain](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain) page sort of have an example of this, but I'll try to simplify it.

It seems bare repos still have an index, which can be manipulated and made into a commit. It's probably also possible to create tree object from scratch, but I'm not aware of exactly how.

You probably have to lock the repository if there's a risk someone else might access it at the same time. I'll simply use `lockfile` from the `procmail` package here.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd myrepo.git

MY_BRANCH=master
MY_FILE_CONTENTS=$'Hello, world!\n'

# Note this is just a lock for this script. It's not honored by other tools.
lockfile -1 -r 10 lock || exit 1

PARENT_COMMIT="$(git show-ref -s "$MY_BRANCH")"

# Empty the index, not sure if this step is necessary
git read-tree --empty

# Load the current tree. A commit ref is fine, it'll figure it out.
git read-tree "${PARENT_COMMIT}"

# Create a blob object. Some systems have "shasum" instead of "sha1sum"
# Might want to check if it already exists. Left as an excercise. :)
BLOB_ID=$(printf "blob %d\0%s" $(echo -n "$MY_FILE_CONTENTS" | wc -c) "$MY_FILE_CONTENTS" | sha1sum | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
mkdir -p "objects/${BLOB_ID:0:2}"
printf "blob %d\0%s" $(echo -n "$MY_FILE_CONTENTS" | wc -c) "$MY_FILE_CONTENTS" | perl -MCompress::Zlib -e 'undef $/; print compress(<>)' > "objects/${BLOB_ID:0:2}/${BLOB_ID:2}"

# Now add it to the index.
git update-index --add --cacheinfo 100644 "$BLOB_ID" "myfile.txt"

# Create a tree from your new index
TREE_ID=$(git write-tree)

# Commit it.
NEW_COMMIT=$(echo "My commit message" | git commit-tree "$TREE_ID" -p "$PARENT_COMMIT")

# Update the branch
git update-ref "refs/heads/$MY_BRANCH" "$NEW_COMMIT" "$PARENT_COMMIT"

# Done
rm -f lock
```

It'd be nice if there were git commands to create blobs, but I didn't find one. The perl command was taken from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3185337/622060).

Comment: As for how to create a tree/blob object from scratch, there seems to be a command called `git hash-object` that can do that for you, and it also adds it to the object store when passing it the `-w` flag. http://git-scm.com/docs/git-hash-object

Answer (score 3):

The ["Plumbing and Porcelain"](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain) chapter of Pro Git provides some insight into the internals of Git, which you could leverage into a way to create commits while bypassing some of the normal Git process.

Comment: Never fully resolved this but congrats on having the best answer!

Answer (score 2):

I created the sample for git add/rm files into bare repo using JGit.
Check out https://github.com/junoyoon/git-online-commit-sample. In the test code you can know how to use JGit APIs for bare repo manipulation.