# Building git commit objects with git hash-object?

Tags: git

How can i manually build git commit objects using git hash-object?
I now it works with blobs, and its documentation says it can build different objects by using -t  but how do you build a commit with that?

Comment: You'll need to make some tree objects to make a commit object. You can use an index file and `write-tree` or just `mktree`. You _can_ use `hash-object` if you really want but it seems like a lot of hassle to me.

Comment: Do you know how to use hash-object to do that? I am aware of the existence of git commit-tree but can you do that with git hash-object?

Comment: You just pipe a valid tree to it, just as you would any other object, such as blob.

Comment: You can see raw contents with `git cat-file`, e.g. `git cat-file commit master`, `git cat-file tree master^{tree}`.

Comment: In particular, `git rev-parse master` and `git cat-file commit master | git hash-object -t commit --stdin` will give the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a complete and working example of a script that creates a `commit` object without ever running `git commit`:

```
mkdir project
cd project
git init

hash=`echo -n "" | git hash-object -w --stdin`

tree=`echo -e "100644 blob ${hash}\temptyfile" | git mktree`

commit=`echo -e "yourname\nyour@email.com\n2013 12:20:15 +0200\ncommittername\ncommitter@email.com\n2013 10:13:15 +0200" | git commit-tree ${tree}`

git update-ref refs/heads/master ${commit}
```

To verify that the script created a commit containing an empty file, run:

```
git checkout --
git log --oneline
#2abbdc2 yourname your@email.com 2013 12:20:15 +0200 committername committer@email.com
```

Edit: fixed and improved

Comment: is it "\tempfile" or "\temtyfile" ?

Comment: @qbolec `\t` stands for `TAB` character, so yes, it's `\temptyfile`.  However giving it wrong as `\tempfile` this only means, it shows up as `empfile` in the `git`-worktree.  So the filename used for `git hash-object` does not neccessarily need to be the same for `git mktree`.

Answer (score 2):

For the benefit of the reader:

The [accepted answer from Arialdo Martini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19423775) is fully correct and explains how to create an empty `git` repo with proper plumbing commands.  Please note that his variant works for `bare` repositories, too (you can create `emptyfile` in the `git`-dir with no bad sideeffects).

This answer here sums it up into a script with a minor tweak:  The contents of the file is taken from "stdin" and the file can be placed into a sub-directory of the worktree.

Script `git-init-with-file-from-stdin.sh new-git-workdir filename 'commit message'`:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir "$1" &&
cd "$1" &&
git init &&

dir="$(dirname "$2")" &&
name="$(basename "${2:-dummyfile}")" &&

obid="$(git hash-object -w --stdin)" &&
treeid="$(git mktree < <(printf '100644 blob %q\t%q\n' "$obid" "$name"))" &&

if [ . = "$dir" ]; then git read-tree -i "$treeid";
else git read-tree --prefix="$dir/" -i "$treeid"; fi &&

git commit -m "${3:-automatic commit}" &&
git reset --hard
```

Explained for the call

```
    ./git-init-with-file-from-stdin.sh newgitdir path/to/file <<< "hellOw W0rld"
```

- `mkdir "$1"`, `cd "$1"`, `git init` creates the new `git` worktree and initiailizes it.  It is named after the first argument (here `newgitdir`), which is assumed to name a nonexisting directory in an existing path.
- `dir="$(dirname "$2")"`, `name="$(basename "${2:-dummyfile}")"` extracts the path and the name part of the second argument, which defines the wanted filename.  The path is relative to the created `git`-workdir.  Note that this argument must not start with a `/`, else the command fails.  Here `dir=path/to` and `name=file`.  If left away, the new file is called "dummyfile" in the top of the `git`-workdir.
- `obid="$(git hash-object -w --stdin)"` then stores the object with the information read from `stdin` into the `git` repo and stores the SHA (object id) of the new object in the variable `obid`.  In the example, the contents is `hellOw W0rld` followed by an `NL`.
- `git mktree < <(printf '100644 blob %q\t%q\n' "$obid" "$name")` is nearly the same as `printf '100644 blob %q\t%q\n' "$obid" "$name" | git mktree` and creates a proper git-tree.  `100644` is the usual file mode.  If you want to create executables, you need `100755` here.
- `treeid="$(`...`)"` then assigns this to the given variable `treeid`
- `if [ . = "$dir" ]; then git read-tree -i "$treeid";` this reads this newly created tree into the `git` staging area for later commit.  However this is for the case, that the file shall be directly in the `git`-workdir.
- `else git read-tree --prefix="$dir/" -i "$treeid"; fi` is the same for the case, when you want to put it into a subdirectory of the `git`-workdir.  The nice thing is, that `git` creates all intermediate directory nodes for you, automatically.  (Sadly `--prefix="./"` produces an error.)
- `git commit -m "${3:-automatic commit}"` then uses the well-known commit to create the commit
- `git reset --hard` then syncs the `git`-worktree with the latest commit.

Changes for `bare` variant:

- Everything works similar, except `git commit` (this needs a workdir) and `git reset` (you do not need it).
- replace

  ```
  git init &&
  ```

  with

  ```
  git init --bare &&
  ```

  also replace

  ```
  git commit -m "${3:-automatic commit}" &&
  git reset --hard
  ```

  with a similar sequence as seen in the accepted answer:

  ```
  commitid="$(git commit-tree "$(git write-tree)" <<< "${3:-automatic commit}")" &&
  git update-ref "refs/heads/master" "$commitid"
  ```

Remarks:

- See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/25556917
- This here needs `bash`, which means, [it works for Windows 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/commandline/wsl/install_guide), too

Comment: Do you know, If I already has file in index and replacing it using `git update index` command do i need to remove old object manually?