# How to read a .deflate file in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I got some `pig` generated files with `part-r-00000.deflate` extension. I know this is a compressed file. How do I generate a normal file in a readable format. When I used `hadoop fs -text`, I cannot get plaintext output. The output is still binary. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 20):

You might be using a [quite old](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-6714) Hadoop version (e.g: 0.20.0) in which fs -text can't inflate the compressed file.

As a workaround you may try this one-liner (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3185337/1050422) answer):

```
hadoop fs -text file.deflate | perl -MCompress::Zlib -e 'undef $/; print uncompress(<>)'
```

Answer (score 17):

you can decompress on the fly by using this command

`hdfs dfs -text file.deflate | hdfs dfs -put - uncompressed_destination_file`