# Where does git store blob object?

Tags: git

I understand that git compress the file and then calculate the SHA1 and store that in `.git/objects/` and we can see the content using `git cat-file -p 'sha1'` but I am interested to know where does git store the compressed blob objects.

as mentioned in the following post

http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/02/17/how-git-stores-your-data.html

Update
I can only see `SHA1` in `.git/objects` which I think are reference to the actual blob rather than blob

Comment: Errr..., compressed blob stored in .git/objects. Don't understand what the question is.

Comment: @AlexeyTen I think .git/objects only store the SHA1 I do not see any object in that directory

Comment: @mu無 I can not see anything else but the SHA1 in .git/objects

Comment: @Ashish yep, that's files named as SHA1 of their content.

Comment: @Ashish Are you sure you are looking at the right directory? In one of my repos, I can clearly see files of the kind `.git/objects/fd/0b949f2d8db5b2a518e8adb10a39c81a1fc399` where `fd0b949f2d8db5b2a518e8adb10a39c81a1fc399` would be the SHA, and the insides of the file is some binary garbled text.

Comment: @AlexeyTen thanks, so I wanted to know where that blob store

Comment: @Ashish may be you need to read this http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I understand that git compress the file and then calculate the SHA1

Git computes the SHA1 hash of the uncompressed file, Then it compresses the data and stores it in .git/objects, using the SHA1 as the filename.

Example:

1. create a test repository

```
$ mkdir tmp
$ cd tmp
$ git init .
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/.git/
```

2. add a test file

```
$ echo 'hello, world' > hello.txt
$ git add hello.txt
$ git commit -m "Initial commit"
[master (root-commit) 951d5cc] Initial commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 hello.txt
```

3. display the test file's content in the .git/objects directory

```
$ git hash-object hello.txt
4b5fa63702dd96796042e92787f464e28f09f17d
$ cat .git/objects/4b/5fa63702dd96796042e92787f464e28f09f17d
xKOR04fQ(I??
$ python -c "import zlib,sys;print repr(zlib.decompress(sys.stdin.read()))" < .git/objects/4b/5fa63702dd96796042e92787f464e28f09f17d
'blob 13\x00hello, world\n'
```

The script in the last line is from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8326032/365496) answer.

As you can see, the file content in .git/objects is not viewable directly, `cat` displays it only as `xKOR04fQ(I??`. The file is also not stored in a standard container for compressed data, but using zlib you can decrompress the raw data. The stored file also contains git metadata about the content: the type of git object and the length of the content. But the data is clearly stored right there in .git/objects:

```
blob 13\x00hello, world\n
```

Comment: And that's a first part of git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects :)