# How to manually create Git blob without Git?

Tags: git, hash, blob, zlib

For educational purpose, I would like to manually create a Git Blob without Git.

I've read that Git uses zlib and sha256, so I wrote this:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> import zlib

>>> open('hello.txt', 'w').write('Hello World!\n')
>>> hashlib.sha256(zlib.compress(open('hello.txt', 'r').read().encode())).hexdigest()
'df46eac3bcbac69a75fbc5f87fe82c5f12c4991a9610805fc3fade2bb33fbb25'
```

However I don't get the same as Git:

```
$ git cat-file -p d712
100644 blob 980a0d5f19a64b4b30a87d4206aade58726b60e3    hello.txt
```

What am I missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28416702/717372

Comment: This one also could help https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+how+objects+hash+calculated

Comment: `printf 'Hello, World!\n' | git hash-object --stdin` ->
8ab686eafeb1f44702738c8b0f24f2567c36da6d ; 
`printf 'blob 14\0Hello, World!\n' | sha1sum -` ->
8ab686eafeb1f44702738c8b0f24f2567c36da6d