# Uncompressing zlib file in command line

Tags: git, unix, zlib, compression

When Git stores a snapshot of a file, it stores an object called a blob.

This is compressed using zlib..see http://nfarina.com/post/9868516270/git-is-simpler; either I am blind or he doesn't explain how the file blob was uncompressed in the fist place (while everything else was explained as if to a noob)

How do we extract this and view the contents of a blob ? Most of the results from googling this applied to uncompressing within scripts/programs, not manual/CL:

[Deflate command line tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178566/deflate-command-line-tool), 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22834

I was looking for a single one-line command line way to do this on a single file.

Thanks in advance!

(Even if this question sounds like a duplicate, the barrage of answers in the other link are no way as accurate as the one here. I think this thread should be kept alive or this answer be posted there to help others with a non-convoluted way to deflate)

Comment: "openssl zlib -d" does what was asked for: uncompressing of zlib-file via command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `git cat-file -p SHA1` to view the file content of the blob.

The content of the file is this: `blob XXX NULL Content`

ex:

a.txt contain Hello World

The Content of the SHA-1 is:

`blob 11\000Hello World` and this strign is then GZipped

If you are on unix u can use this to deflate the content:
`perl -MCompress::Zlib -e 'undef $/; print uncompress(<>)'`

Comment: I tried this, like I mentioned above.

This is what happens: <br/>

   @precise32:~/gs$ git cat-file -p .git/objects/1b/2a93ec2d9f68e802d5d106983a395b368f0d36
    fatal: Not a valid object name .git/objects/1b/2a93ec2d9f68e802d5d106983a395b368f0d36`

Comment: just the SHA no path. git cat-file -p 1b2a93ec2d9f68e802d5d106983a395b368f0d36

Comment: <br/>
~/gs/.git/objects/a5$ ls
bce3fd2565d8f458555a0c6f42d0504a848bd5
<br/>
~/gs/.git/objects/a5$ git cat-file -p bce3fd2565d8f458555a0c6f42d0504a848bd5
<br/>
fatal: Not a valid object name bce3fd2565d8f458555a0c6f42d0504a848bd5

Comment: you need 40 characters. 2 are the folder name and 38 are the file name if you take it from the .git folder. If you have the id from `git ls-tree -s` then you already have the full id.

Comment: Ahh...classic noobie faux pas...thanks a bunch !!