# Database file with 78 9C header?

Tags: database, binary, zlib, b-tree

I've come to work with a strange database file format.
Each DB comes with two files: one is "database.db" and the other is "database.key".

The ".db" file always starts with a 0x78 0x9C binary header, while the ".key" always contains, in a random part of the file, the string "1.00 Peter's B Tree" inside.

Looking online I found that the header 0x78 0x9C could refer to compression Zlib, but have not found any way to view the contents of the database.

Does anyone here know something that could help me with this format ? Thnaks :)

**Edit 1:**
It appears that the ".db" file contains more than one zlib deflated streams:
The signature 0x78 0x9C is not only present at the beginning of the file but in different parts of it.
Fo example this are some of the streams i can find in one file:

```
78 9C CB 63 40 07 33 76 5B 6A AF 78 DD 54 23 CE C9 90 C4 78 89 81 89 81 F1 22 86 9A ED 6A D7 44 F6 03 D5 B0 31 30 94 60 91 F6 D4 2A 76 3B 0C 94 E6 63 60 2C 51 B6 63 00 00 22 13 11 57
78 9C CB 63 40 07 2F 53 D7 B8 9F EC 8B B2 E1 7A F1 32 87 F1 12 03 23 03 E3 45 0C 35 4B B7 68 5B CD 90 2E E7 65 67 60 2A 51 B6 63 00 00 A6 E8 0C 5D
```

By inflating thoose 2 streams i get 2 new uncompressed streams.

What i did then is a C# program that loaded a ".db" file and created a list of byte arrays; a byte array is a deflated stream.
To do this I simply split the file at every 78 9C.

This seems to work with some of the ".db" files but, in other situations it gave me some errors like "Invalid distance code", with this stream

```
78 9C E2 13 FD 2F 14 9F CD 9B 29 3E 65 9F A0 F8 BC 7C 92 E2 93 EF 29 8A CF B0 A7 29 3E 8D FE 4A F1 B9 F2 0C C5 27 C4 B3 14 EF F5 5B 28 DE B5 B7 52 BC FF 6E A3 78 27 DD 4E F1 9E B8 83 E2 DD 6D 27 C5 FB D4 2E FA F0 6A EE A6 78 EF 78 EE EA 2F AA D3 91 FE 1F 2F 94 78 6C
```

or "Invalid stored block lenght", with this stream

```
78 9C 90 35 CE 34 2F 0C 7D FE A5 57 C9 FF D5 2B 47 5B B7 C4 7F 69 EA 3F 0F AC 25 F4 45 49 3D CC FF 00 E5 AE 30 40
```

Maybe simply splitting the file at each 78 9C is not the correct way of doing it ...

As for the ".key" files: I was able to open them using the library of Peter Graf "PBL".
With the "pblKfGetAbs ()" (http://www.mission-base.com/peter/source/pbl/doc/keyfile.html) I managed to get all records related to each key in the file. These records are of 4-byte values.
Searching for these values on a decompressed ".db" file (In a file that did not give me errors during the inflate process) with an hex editor I was able to get some results but nothing more. I don't understand wat thoose records on the key file means...

Thank you for the help !

Comment: "peter's B tree" -> http://www.mission-base.com/peter/source/pbl/pblkf.c

Comment: Ok but what can i do with that? :/ That not a way of seeing the content of the database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a zlib header look like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050260/what-does-a-zlib-header-look-like)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, those are very likely [zlib](http://zlib.net/) streams stored in the database.

There is nothing keeping `78 9c` from appearing in the compressed data, so simply searching for that is not a good way to extract the contents of the file. Also `78 9c` is not the only valid zlib header. The easiest way to find the valid zlib streams is to simply start decompressing at every byte. zlib will very quickly rule out most as not having a valid zlib header. For the rest you can decompress until it completes or fails. If it completes with a good integrity check (returning `Z_STREAM_END`), then it is extremely likely that that was an intentional compressed zlib stream.

You are trying to reverse-engineer a data base format with what appears to be relatively little to go on. This is a detective job that stackoverflow can't help with, unless someone here knows the format and recognizes it.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.
Right now the language or enviroment are not important. Thoose are "old" db files that where created by someone inside my company that now is no longer working here, and we must open them.
I've tryed to decompress the zlib streams with java in Windows but the output isn't less confusing ..

Comment: When you tried to decompress, did it succeed? Success would be no error codes.

Comment: You are right, an error code appeared.
The .db file however seems composed of more deflated data stream.. I can find multiple 0x789C inside the file.
I've made a program to split the binary file at each 0x789C occurrence,and then inflate each one of these data streams. However this does not seem to work completely ...

Comment: Please expand your question with what you have tried and in what way it appears to have not fully worked.

Answer (score 2):

These are [`zlib` magic headers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9050260/55075) widely used by different utilities (such as [Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28753259/55075), Memcached, etc).

To uncompress the file, you can use the following command:

```
printf "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" | cat - zlib-file.dump | gunzip
```

To skip some bytes before, use `dd`, e.g.

```
cat <(printf "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00") <(dd skip=100 if=zlib-file.dump bs=1 of=/dev/stdout) | gunzip
```

If the data got *crc/length error*, consider as faulty.

Answer (score 0):

the .db files are compressed data , the .key files are key_informations to find the wanted data in those .db (like an index file) after you open them,you may not find string data in those .db files,because they are a runtime databases, these .db files containt hex data like 'packets'and they are compressed as he said

Answer (score 0):

[`78 9C`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17176881/993047) is the zlib magic headers with *Default Compression*.

Try [Aluigi's offzip](http://aluigi.org/mytoolz/offzip.zip) commandline tool to extract the data.