# How to make next git commit to exactly represent project state from another commit without merge?

Tags: git

I have two git branches: Alpha and Beta and I need to create next commit on the branch Alpha so its project state would be exactly the same like on branch Beta. Without merge.

I understand that every git commit - on a logical level - is a complete and immutable project state + some metadata. So I just need branch Alpha to have the same state of files like Beta does.

It would be another commit (with different hash), and one branch tip wouldn't reference another.

Comment: You may read the manual of [git-format-patch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch) and [git-apply](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply) to achieve your goal without merge

Comment: @TravorLiu, yes its possible to create a patch based on their diff, and the apply it. But it I believe there should be a simpler and more elegant way. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
c=$(git commit-tree Beta^{tree} -p Alpha -m 'foo')
test $c && git update-ref refs/heads/Alpha $c
```

`git commit-tree` creates a new commit, whose tree is the same with Beta's tip's and whose parent is Alpha's tip.

`git update-ref` makes Alpha point at the new commit.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Just one-line command `git update-ref refs/heads/Alpha $(git commit-tree Beta^{tree} -p Alpha -m 'foo')`

Comment: That's exactly the right solution. (And it shows that it helps learning the Git object model, [which is really not that complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44872194/2988).) A commit is a pointer to a tree, a set of pointers to parent commits, and some metadata. You already have the tree, all you need is to construct the commit.

Answer (score 3):

But it I believe there should be a simpler and more elegant way.

There is a way which does not involve patches: `reset --hard` followed by `reset --soft`.

- First, mark the current HEAD of your branch: we will need to move that HEAD *without* modifying `Alpha`, so let's create a new temporary branch called '`tmp`' where `Alpha` is.

  ```
  git checkout Alpha
  git checkout -b tmp
  ```
- Then we go back to an Beta HEAD commit with the right content.

  ```
  git reset --hard Beta
  ```

That resets the index (and working tree) to the right content, but that also moves HEAD. However, that moves `tmp` HEAD, not `Alpha` HEAD.

- move back `tmp` HEAD to where `mAlphaaster` is, but without modifying the index or the working tree (which are representing what we need for a new commit)

  ```
  git reset --soft Alpha
  ```
- make a new commit, on top of `Alpha`/`tmp` HEAD, which represents the right content (Beta HEAD commit content).

  ```
  git commit -m "new commit, image of an old one"
  ```
- Finally, force `Alpha` to be where `tmp` is: one new commit later.

  ```
  git branch -M tmp Alpha
  git checkout Alpha
  git branch -d tmp
  ```

Now a regular `git push` is enough, any collaborator can simply pull as usual, and still get the old reset content.

```
git push
```