# git rebase: why do I get conflicts rebasing on top of the same state as the common ancestor?

Tags: git, rebase, git-merge-conflict

I would like to better understand something I am observing with Git, using `git --version 2.39.2`.

In a repo, I have two long-lived branches, the default `master` and a `new` one, branched from `master` several months ago. In the last months, there was some maintenance work done in `master`, with occasional cherry-picking into `new`. On the other hand, there was a lot of work on `new`, with many PRs merged into it and more than 600 commits on top of the branching point.

I now want to rebase `new` on top of `master`, to then merge `new` into `master`. When rebasing, I had a few minor conflicts, which however risked to spoil the history, as for instance they would make it harder to track which dependency versions were used exactly back in time. I thus decided to do the following:

1. I added (locally) a commit to `master`, bringing its state back to the common ancestor of the two branches. I used this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51906191/6760680
2. I then rebased `new` on top of this "edited" `master`, which also implies that it's rebased on top of the remote `master`, so I can use this rebased version to merge.

Now, the question is: *why did I still get some (small) conflicts, when doing this procedure?*

I was rebasing on top of a state that was identical to the common ancestor of the two branches, so I expected no conflict at all. I am slightly worried that the history might be messed up due to this (hard to check, as it's many commits, as I said), even if the final state of the branch is the expected one. Note that I rebased with the `--rebase-merges` option, because I want to keep the merge commits, not sure if that can be related. Can somebody with deeper Git insights illuminate me?

Comment: I think you have _merges_ in `new`? Did you use `git rebase --rebase-merges`?

Comment: As stated in the question, yes.

Comment: You usually do not rebase such a complicated branch, especially if you are going to merge it to master anyway. Why do you want to rebase it?

Comment: Because I cannot merge the non-rebased `new`, due to the conflicts between the two branches. However, I don't want to simply rename the branches (or switch the default, because I want to bring in the changes made in `master`, and I would prefer to do that with a merge rather than by cherry-picking).

Comment: And, yes, I could merge `master` into `new` first, but the question is not so much about the practical aspects, I solved those. I would like to better understand how Git works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok..... I think your problem is the rebase *itself*, at least current git's implementation for rebasing merges.... even if you use `--rebase-merges` and the trees involved are exactly one like the other to start with, if there is a conflict with a merge, git **does not** care for the trees been the same and will let you do the conflict resolution instead of using the tree of the original merge commit. We will someday tackle this in upstream *but* for the time being, I can offer this script:

https://github.com/eantoranz/git/blob/replay/contrib/replay

I haven't used it in a while so take it with a grain of salt... the good thing is that it *doesn't* move anything around.... it will print a commit ID after it has run. That commit has the rebased history, feel free to put a branch there when you are sure that branch history is what you want to have.

Answer (score 0):

Rebasing is a more complicated operation than a merge. Merge creates one commit, and all the conflicts you might have are resolved in this one commit. Rebase creates multiple commits (all of the existing commits are re-done), and conflicts might occur in any of them. The more complicated your history of changes, the less you should use rebase and the more you should use merge.

In your (pretty standard) use case simply merge `new` to `master` and solve all the conflicts.

Another a little more safe solution is with two merges:

1. Merge `master` into `new`. Resolve any of the conflicts in `new`.
2. Merge `new` back to `master`. There should be no conflicts.

This approach allows you to test the `new` branch after the merge to make sure you didn't break anything with the merge.

As for your original question, I suppose the reason for the small conflicts you get is that there are more common ancestors of `new` and `master` apart from your original branching point. I think someone merged `master` into `new` (probably indirectly via some other branch`) during the long course of development. Honestly, I am not even completely sure how git is doing rebase in this situation.