# How to compare Github API hash with a local file hash?

Tags: c++, git, github, github-api, git-plumbing

I'm trying to compare the hash of local files with the hash from the `GitHub` API;

I have created `test.txt` and uploaded it to my [repo](https://github.com/jajabu33/test/blob/main/test.txt), when I call `compute_sha1_hash` on
`test.txt`:

`2aae6c35c94fcfb415dbe95f408b9ce91ee846ed`

The `GitHub` API response:

```json
      "path": "test.txt",
      "mode": "100644",
      "type": "blob",
      "sha": "95d09f2b10159347eece71399a7e2e907ea3df4f",
```

From what I've searched looks like GitHub uses `SHA1`, why the values doesn't match?

Do I need to do any kind of calc in this hash to retrieve the "local file hash"?

I have written a working **example**:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

std::string compute_sha1_hash(const std::string& file_path)
{
    std::ifstream file(file_path, std::ios::binary);
    if (!file) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Could not open file");
    }

    EVP_MD_CTX* mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_new();
    if (mdctx == NULL) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create EVP_MD_CTX");
    }

    if (EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx, EVP_sha1(), NULL) != 1) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to initialize SHA-1 context");
    }

    std::vector<char> buffer(4096);
    while (file.read(buffer.data(), buffer.size())) {
        if (EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, buffer.data(), file.gcount()) != 1) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to update SHA-1 context");
        }
    }

    if (file.gcount() > 0) {
        if (EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, buffer.data(), file.gcount()) != 1) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to update SHA-1 context");
        }
    }

    std::vector<unsigned char> hash_value(EVP_MD_size(EVP_sha1()));
    unsigned int digest_len;
    if (EVP_DigestFinal_ex(mdctx, hash_value.data(), &digest_len) != 1) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to finalize SHA-1 context");
    }

    EVP_MD_CTX_free(mdctx);

    // Convert to hex
    std::ostringstream oss;
    for (const auto& byte : hash_value) {
        oss << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(byte);
    }

    return oss.str();
}

// Brian613542705's answer
std::string compute_sha1_hash_2(const std::string& file_path)
{
   std::ifstream file(file_path, std::ios::binary);
   if (!file) {
      throw std::runtime_error("Could not open file");
   }

   // Read the content of the file
   std::ostringstream oss;
   oss << file.rdbuf();
   std::string content = oss.str();

   // Prepend "blob " and the size of the content
   std::string preparedContent = "blob " + std::to_string(content.size()) + "\0" + content;

   EVP_MD_CTX* mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_new();
   if (mdctx == NULL) {
      throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create EVP_MD_CTX");
   }

   if (EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx, EVP_sha1(), NULL) != 1) {
      throw std::runtime_error("Failed to initialize SHA-1 context");
   }

   if (EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, preparedContent.c_str(), preparedContent.size()) != 1) {
      throw std::runtime_error("Failed to update SHA-1 context");
   }

   std::vector<unsigned char> hash_value(EVP_MD_size(EVP_sha1()));
   unsigned int digest_len;
   if (EVP_DigestFinal_ex(mdctx, hash_value.data(), &digest_len) != 1) {
      throw std::runtime_error("Failed to finalize SHA-1 context");
   }

   EVP_MD_CTX_free(mdctx);

   // Convert to hex
   std::ostringstream sha1oss;
   for (const auto& byte : hash_value) {
      sha1oss << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(byte);
   }

   return sha1oss.str();
}

 static size_t WriteMemoryCallback(void* contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp) 
 {
     size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
     auto& mem = *static_cast<std::string*>(userp);
     mem.append(static_cast<char*>(contents), realsize);
     return realsize;
 }

void curl(std::string& data, const char* url)
{
    CURL* curl_handle = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE, 0);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);  // redirects
    CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
        std::cerr << "curl_easy_perform failed: " << curl_easy_strerror(res) << '\n';
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);
    curl_global_cleanup();
}

int main() 
{
    std::string fileHash = compute_sha1_hash("C:/Users/jabu/test.txt");
    std::string fileHash_2 = compute_sha1_hash_2("C:/Users/jabu/test.txt");
    std::string jsonString;
    curl(jsonString, "https://api.github.com/repos/jajabu33/test/git/trees/main?recursive=1");

    // just to kick compare the strings
    std::regex shaPattern("\"sha\":\\s*\"([a-fA-F0-9]+)\"");
    std::sregex_iterator shaIterator(jsonString.begin(), jsonString.end(), shaPattern);
    std::sregex_iterator endIterator;

    std::string githubHash;
    for (; shaIterator != endIterator; ++shaIterator)
    {
        std::smatch match = *shaIterator;
        if (match.size() >= 2)
            githubHash = match[1].str();
    }

    if (fileHash == githubHash)
        std::cout << "Hashes are equal\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Hashes are not equal\n";
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**
I have added the function `compute_sha1_hash_2` which does what `Brian61354270` has answered, but the hashes still doesn't match.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44872194/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+blob+calculate+SHA-1

Answer (score 3):

You're looking at the hash (aka object ID) of a [*blob*](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefblobobjectablobobject), not the hash of the file. Blobs are the object type that git uses to store the contents of files. They contain a header in addition to the file contents, which is why the blob ID does not match the hash of the file.

In general, to compute the blob ID of a file from its contents, you can use [`git hash-object`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-hash-object):

```
$ git hash-object test.txt
```

To compute the blob ID in C++, you'll need to manually create a blob object for the file and then compute its SHA1 hash.  Fortunately, this is an easy task. Start by creating the blob header, which has the form

```
blob <size>\0
```

where `<size>` is the size of the file in bytes, written as an ASCII decimal number, and `\0` is a null-byte. The header is immediately follow by the contents of the file to form the complete blob object.

You can self-check that you got the header right by comparing the SHA1 hash of your constructed blob object with the output of `git hash-object`. For example, say we have a file of length 3 with the contents `foo`. The full blob object is then `blob 3\0foo`, which SHA1-hashes to `19102815...`. Checking this against `git hash-object`, we see that we get a match:

```
$ echo -n "foo" | git hash-object --stdin
19102815663d23f8b75a47e7a01965dcdc96468c
$ echo -n $'blob 3\0foo' | sha1sum 
19102815663d23f8b75a47e7a01965dcdc96468c  -
```

See  [Git Internals - Git Objects](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) from the git book for more on how objects are stored in git.

Comment: I dont understand what you did, but these values in your proof of concept is different from the "local hash" `2aae6c35c94fcfb415dbe95f408b9ce91ee846ed` and how i would call these commands from C++?

Comment: @Jabu The proof of concept is for a file with the contents `foo`. If you apply the same steps to your `test.txt` file, you should get a hash that matches the blob hash returned by GitHub, `95d09f2...`

Comment: @Jabu You don't need to call these commands from C++. In your code, you can use any SHA1 implementation you like

Comment: I still dont understand how to compare the hashs, could you give an example in c++ and with the file i used in the code above?

Comment: @Jabu Computing the blob hash is no different from computing the local file's hash. You just need to append the blob header as described above. If you need help with a specific part of that (e.g. how to append a string to the in memory contents of a file), you can create a specific question for that.

Comment: I have added into the question the function `compute_sha1_hash_2` which does what you said, prepend `blob <size>\0` followed by the file content, and the hashes still doesn't match.

Comment: @Jabu `"\0"` is treated as an empty string. Try [`"\0"s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s). See also [How do you construct a std::string with an embedded null?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/164168/11082165)