# Replicating `git hash-object` with non-ascii characters

Tags: git, hash, character-encoding, sha

Trying to replicate hash-object I found that is not working when using non-ascii characters.

```
$ printf hola | git hash-object -w --stdin
b8b4a4e2a5db3ebed5f5e02beb3e2d27bca9fc9a
$ printf "blob 4\0hola" | shasum
b8b4a4e2a5db3ebed5f5e02beb3e2d27bca9fc9a
```

But if I add the Pound symbol

```
$ printf hola£ | git hash-object -w --stdin
8f9852933655612593d0bbd43c9f7c6f25d947a0
$ printf "blob 5\0hola£" | shasum
54386ef126fcfc9e8242c6d6bade401b1f27999a
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Related: [How to assign a Git SHA1's to a file without Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552659/how-to-assign-a-git-sha1s-to-a-file-without-git/552725#552725)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The number defines number of bytes, not characters**

£ in UTF-8 is 2-byte wide (0xc2 0xa3), thus:

`printf "blob 6\0hola£" | shasum` is what you want

which returns `8f9852933655612593d0bbd43c9f7c6f25d947a0` as expected.

**Check yourself:**

Unpack the content of the just written object:

```
printf "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" | cat - .git/objects/8f/9852933655612593d0bbd43c9f7c6f25d947a0 | gzip -dc | xxd
```

(or use pigz: [Deflate command line tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178566/deflate-command-line-tool))