# How can it be that a commit object has 2 authors?

Tags: git

The commit `487128950df6ee433c131b5feaafe81ee86629f4` can be found at https://github.com/signalwire/freeswitch.git.

`git log -1 487128950df6ee433c131b5feaafe81ee86629f4 --pretty=fuller` prints:

```
commit 487128950df6ee433c131b5feaafe81ee86629f4
Author:     Travis Cross <tc@traviscross.com>
AuthorDate: Fri Mar 21 06:12:02 2014 +0000
Author:     Anthony Minessale <anthm@freeswitch.org>
AuthorDate: Fri Mar 14 02:59:13 2014 +0500
Commit:     Travis Cross <tc@traviscross.com>
CommitDate: Mon Mar 24 12:54:50 2014 +0000

    Use the system version of APR / APR-util if possible

    Autodetect whether the system libapr / libaprutil has our
    necessary modifications and use it if it does.
```

It has 2 authors. Pushing this commit to Gitlab or Github could fail if fsck check is on, complaining `remote: error: object 487128950df6ee433c131b5feaafe81ee86629f4: multipleAuthors: invalid format - multiple 'author' lines`.

I'm curious how this commit was created. One of the solutions to record multiple authors is appending `Co-authored-by` in the commit message. As it's possible to create a commit with two authors, why hasn't it been a built-in method? And why is such a commit considered as a bad object by `git fsck`?

Comment: Note the 2014 date: back then, Git didn't do as much consistency checking (and/or perhaps people thought that Git should allow multiple author lines at the time). There are a number of similar historical oddities, which is why `git fsck` has all those configuration entries for determining whether any particular error is a hard error or just a warning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A git commit object is [just a compressed text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178566/how-to-deflate-with-a-command-line-tool-to-extract-a-git-object). This one happens to have two authors.

```
$ pigz -d < .git/objects/48/7128950df6ee433c131b5feaafe81ee86629f4 
commit 438tree 070633dfc3ea352dfb1094822f477111e519a9ca
parent cde20f6fe68523d9416d2fed72435a8ba880a269
author Travis Cross <tc@traviscross.com> 1395382322 +0000
author Anthony Minessale <anthm@freeswitch.org> 1394747953 +0500
committer Travis Cross <tc@traviscross.com> 1395665690 +0000

Use the system version of APR / APR-util if possible

Autodetect whether the system libapr / libaprutil has our
necessary modifications and use it if it does.
```

> *I'm curious how this commit was created.*

You'd have to ask Travis Cross for exactly how they did it.
Making a commit is [not much more than writing text to a file](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/commit.c#L1440).

> *Why is such a commit considered as a bad object by git fsck?*

Internally, [Git can only have one author per commit](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/commit.c#L1311). Allowing multiple authors would require reworking the internals.

While `git-log` will display multiple authors that's probably an implementation quirk. Other tools will not honor both authors. For example, `git shortlog --group=author` only counts the commit to Anthony Minessale.

If you need multiple authors, [add co-authors](https://github.blog/2018-01-29-commit-together-with-co-authors/) via ["trailers"](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-interpret-trailers).