# Parse the git index file and save to text file

Tags: regex, git, file, parsing

How to read `git index` file and extract all paths to text file?

except

> git ls-files > out.txt

I mean using other things like regex or something else?

Comment: Depends on Operating System, but you can pipe output on linux and mac http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674327/redirect-all-output-to-file

Comment: _"I mean using other things like regex or something else?"_ The index file itself is a binary file; before regex can be applied to filter the data, the file's contents must first be parsed into readable format, and the `git ls-files` command does exactly that. What exactly speaks against using the git command?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do, `git ls-files > out.txt` should do exactly what you want - it reads the contents of the index file in the current git branch and saves them into a text file, in this case `out.txt`. Have you tried using that command, and if so, can you explain how the command's output differs from what you're trying to obtain?

Comment: Do you have git installed on your machine? Without git, it's likely a hassle to try to convert the index file into readable format (according to [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1532405/2191154)). If you do have git installed, simply create a new repository, then copy your index file into the repository and overwrite the existing one. After you've done that, you can read the file using `git ls-files` - I just tried it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the content of the index file, use the command [`git ls-files`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files).
Assuming you're on either Windows, Linux, or Mac, you can reroute the command's output into a text file by using `git ls-files > out.txt`.

See: [What does the git index contain EXACTLY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084921/what-does-the-git-index-contain-exactly)